# one or two sentences?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

The following is a link to a CNN news story.

https://www.facebook.com/cnninternational/videos/this-pool-loving-pup-cant-get-enough-time-in-the-water-see-his-reaction-to-getti/1414625682685648/

There is a sentence I have been puzzling over:

> Thor, the Boston Terrier, loves swimming so much. **He got his own indoor pool**.

I'm wondering if the boldfaced sentence is actually part of the preceding sentence, so that it would be like:

> Thor, the Boston Terrier, loves swimming so much (that) he got his own indoor pool.

Comment: Are you quoting printed text somewhere? That's a video in which the narrator says it as one sentence. She leaves a long pause, but her intonation make it clear it's one sentence.

Comment: Both would be grammatical as 2 sentences (some people don't like "so much" as a standalone phrase but it's common in colloquial English, meaning "very much"). They're also grammatical as one sentence. So really this is just a question about how long a pause is.

Answer (score 0):

The two clauses are independent, but they do clearly relate to each other.  In written English, you can mark this connection with a semicolon.